# Using pubnub in flutter, how to initiate a chat?

Tags: flutter, pubnub

I have a chat app and I am stuck while initiating the chat. According to pubnub, anytime I message to a new channel "A", that channel is created. My problem is that I want to subscribe to that channel and show the message but I cannot subscribe before the channel is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## "Creating" PubNub Channels

Channels are not really "created", channels are just string tokens for routing messages. So there is no notion of creating a channel in PubNub (not officially, anyway).

The phrase "create a channel" is more of a concept than a real thing in PubNub. Within your app, creating a channel (a chat room) is a real thing. So you can `subscribe` to a channel that hasn't yet been "created".

So when your app "creates" a channel (starts a new chat room), your participating clients can `subscribe` to the channel and messages can be `publish`ed later.

Or, clients can `subscribe` after messages are `publish`ed and use `fetchMessages` to get any messages that were sent before the client `subscribe`d.